# LibGDX errno 12 Out of memory

Tags: java, memory, libgdx, out-of-memory

So I'm rather new to lib and im having some issues determining whats causing my out of memory errors:
The program will run for aprox 45 seconds and then crash with the following errors:

```
 <sharedmem_gpumem_alloc_id:1431>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed
 errno 12 Out of memory

 <ioctl_kgsl_sharedmem_alloc:1532>: ioctl_kgsl_sharedmem_alloc: FATAL
 ERROR : (null)
```

MAIN CLASS CODE:

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import java.util.Random;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.PerspectiveCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.VertexAttributes.Usage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Environment;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Material;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Model;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelInstance;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.attributes.ColorAttribute;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.environment.DirectionalLight;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.CameraInputController;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.ModelBuilder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.input.GestureDetector;
import com.badlogic.gdx.input.GestureDetector.GestureListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

public class GDXGame extends ApplicationAdapter implements GestureListener {

    public CameraInputController camController;
    public Environment environment;
    public static PerspectiveCamera cam;
    public ModelBatch modelBatch;

    public Model cube;
    public ModelInstance cube1;
    public Model camCube;
    public ModelInstance camCubeInst;

    public float xPos,yPos,zPos;
    public Vector3 camPos;
    public Vector3 forward;
    public Vector3 side;
    public ModelBuilder modelBuilder;
    public static SpriteBatch batch;

    private button button1;

    @Override
    public void create () {     
        environment = new Environment();
        environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f,0.4f,0.4f,1f));
        environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f,0.8f,0.8f,
                                                    1f,-5f,-2f));
        batch = new SpriteBatch();    

        GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(this);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gd);

        modelBatch = new ModelBatch();

        cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        xPos = 6f;
        yPos = 5f;
        zPos = 6f;

        camPos = new Vector3(xPos,yPos,zPos);
        cam.rotate(45,0,45,0);
        cam.position.set(camPos);
        cam.rotate(45,cam.direction.x,0,-cam.direction.z);

        cam.near = 1f;
        cam.far = 300f;
        cam.update();

        modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
        cube = modelBuilder.createBox(5f,5f,5f,
                new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)),
                Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);
        cube1 = new ModelInstance(cube);
        camCube = modelBuilder.createBox(1f,1f,1f,
                new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.RED)),
                Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);
        camCubeInst = new ModelInstance(camCube);
        camCubeInst.transform.translate(5,3,5);
        camCubeInst.transform.rotate(new Vector3(0,1,0),45);

        button1 = new button(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2,0,0);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {     
        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);        

        cam.update();   

        modelBatch.begin(cam);
        modelBatch.render(cube1, environment);
        modelBatch.render(camCubeInst, environment);
        modelBatch.end();

        batch.begin();
        button1.render();
        batch.end();

    }     
    @Override
    public void resume () {
    }

    @Override
    public void resize (int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause () {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
        Gdx.app.log("DEBUG","TAP x: " + x + "  y: " + y);
        if(x <= (button1.x+button1.image.getWidth()) && x >= button1.x){
            if(y <= (button1.y+button1.image.getHeight()) && y >= button1.y){
                    if(!Gdx.input.isTouched()){
                            button1.bool = true;
                            Random rand = new Random();
                            float r = rand.nextFloat();
                            float g = rand.nextFloat();
                            float b = rand.nextFloat();
                            Color random = new Color(r,g,b,255);
                            cube = modelBuilder.createBox(5f,5f,5f,
                                    new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(random)),
                                    Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);
                            cube1 = new ModelInstance(cube);  
                    }
               }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
        cam.rotate(-45,cam.direction.x,0,-cam.direction.z);
        forward = new Vector3(cam.direction.x,cam.direction.y,cam.direction.z);
        side = new Vector3(cam.direction.cpy().crs(cam.up).nor());
        cam.translate(side.scl(-deltaX/60));
        cam.translate(forward.scl(deltaY/60));
        cam.rotate(45,cam.direction.x,0,-cam.direction.z);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        Gdx.app.log("DEBUG","TAP x: " + x + "  y: " + y);
        if(x <= (button1.x+button1.image.getWidth()) && x >= button1.x){
            if(y <= (button1.y+button1.image.getHeight()) && y >= button1.y){
                    if(!Gdx.input.isTouched()){
                            button1.bool = true;
                            Random rand = new Random();
                            float r = rand.nextFloat()+100;
                            float g = rand.nextFloat()+100;
                            float b = rand.nextFloat()+100;
                            Color random = new Color(r,g,b,255);
                            cube = modelBuilder.createBox(5f,5f,5f,
                                    new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(random)),
                                    Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);
                            cube1 = new ModelInstance(cube);  
                    }
               }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2,
            Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        modelBatch.dispose();
        cube.dispose();
        button1.image.dispose();
        camCube.dispose();
    }
}
```

BUTTON CLASS CODE:

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;

public class button{
        float x;
        float y;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private float w;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private float h;
        Texture image;
        Texture image2;
        Texture drawImage;
        private float touchX,touchY;
        boolean bool;
        public button(float x, float y, float w, float h){
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.w = w;
                this.h = h;
                drawImage = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
                image2 = new Texture("badlogic2.jpg");
                image = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");

        }
        public void render(){
                touchX = Gdx.input.getX();
                touchY = Gdx.input.getY();
                if(Gdx.input.isTouched() && touchX <= (x+image.getWidth()) && touchX >= x && touchY <= (y+image.getHeight()) && touchY >= y){
                    drawImage = image2;
                }
                else{
                    drawImage = image;
                }
                if(bool){
                    drawImage = image;
                    GDXGame.batch.draw(drawImage, x, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - y - image.getHeight());
                    bool = false;
                    Gdx.app.log("DEBUG","Button pressed");

                }
                else{
                    GDXGame.batch.draw(drawImage, x, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - y - image.getHeight());
                }
        }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: oh my god why are you making new textures so many times in the `render()` function, that causes extreme memory leaks, a Texture should be initialized only **once** and disposed at the end of the program in the `dispose()` callback of the `Game` or `ApplicationAdapter` class

Comment: like i said im new, ill mess with it some more thanks for the info :D

Comment: The best practice is having **one** texture file, and selecting TextureRegions from it (read up on TexturePacker and the TextureAtlas if you can't piece them together using Paint or something else). Although I personally only did 2D, not 3D, so no experience with the cubes and stuff. But the `render()` function runs every 50 ms at least, which means you're basically creating 20 texture files per second and Textures are native resources.

Comment: alright i updated my post i just used 3 texture files and made the 3rd one the one that the button draws and it switches based on finger placement, seems to have fixed my issue for now. Yeh thats the next step for me is making a spritesheet, I was just trying to get basic camera/button systems to work and build 1 piece at a time, **Thanks again!**

Comment: @user3408357 I'm glad you were able to get your bug fixed.  However, as it stands, this question isn't that useful for future users.  Updating your question's code with "working" code, sort of breaks the question for future users.  If you want this question to be useful, please leave your original code in the question, and provide an "answer" that explains the fix.  Or just delete your question.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks Bro! 
**don't forget dispose()**